# error 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__dict__'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have encoutered this error and its not letting me save the info in the form. The initial data is showing well in the form but saving is challenging me. Hope someone can help, I'm really stuck

```
class UserPostCreatView(CreateView):
   form_class = PostModelForm
   template_name = 'posts/post_form.html'
   success_url = "/profile/{user_slug}/wall"



def get_initial(self):
    # Get the initial dictionary from the superclass method
    initial = super(UserPostCreatView, self).get_initial()
    user_slug = self.kwargs.get('user_slug')
    user_content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(authomodel.User)
    auth_user = get_object_or_404(authomodel.User, user_slug=user_slug)
    auth_user_id = auth_user.id
    # Copy the dictionary so we don't accidentally change a mutable dict
    initial = initial.copy()
    initial = {
    "content_type": user_content_type,
    "object_id" : auth_user_id,
     }
    return initial

def form_valid(self, form):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())





def get_form_kwargs(self):
    """
    Returns the keyword arguments for instantiating the form.
    """
    kwargs = {
        'initial': self.get_initial(),
    }

    if self.request.method in ('POST', 'PUT'):
        kwargs.update({
            'data': self.request.POST or None, 
            'files': self.request.FILES or None})
    return kwargs


def get_form_class(self):
    return self.form_class
```

> Traceback:
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in
>   inner
>     41.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
>   _legacy_get_response
>     249.             response = self._get_response(request)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
>   _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
>   _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
>     68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in
>   dispatch
>     88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
>     217.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
>     183.             return self.form_valid(form)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\wahab\Desktop\site1\ostra\ostrakodecommerce\posts\views.py"
>   in form_valid
>     207.         return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in
>   get_success_url
>     148.             url = self.success_url.format(**self.object.**dict**)
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /profile/-.1/create Exception Value:
>   'NoneType' object has no attribute '**dict**'

Comment: try to print the user_slug, i guess its coming blank

Comment: Actually that one is doing fine and its the one supplying the initial data, which is showing well in the form

Comment: The challenge comes in saving the data which is already existing in the forms

Comment: Please post the full traceback, which shows where this error is happening.

Comment: @ Daniel Roseman traceback posted

Answer (score 3):

You have overridden the `form_valid` method but haven't done any of the default actions performed by that method, in particular saving the object.

You could fix this by calling the super method, but there is *no point*; redirecting to the success url is what that method does anyway. Remove your `form_valid` method altogether and let the existing definition be called.

Comment: To add to the above, if you want to redirect without saving the record then you should extend [FormView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView)